# SQL Query Two Tables at once and Loop Result as JSON objects

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm not exactly sure what I am looking for here, so apologies if this has already been covered here, I'm not sure what I need to search for!

I have a MySQL database with a table called "Locations" which looks a bit like this

```
id | name | other parameters   
1  | shop1 | blah
2  | shop2 | blah
```

etc

and a table of customer queries

```
id | customer | department
1  | john     | shop2
2  | Joe      | shop2
3  | James    | shop1
4  | Sue      | shop2
```

etc

I want to query this and return a JSON object that looks like this

```
 {"location":"shop1","queryCount":"1"},{"location":"shop2","queryCount":"3"}
```

The location table can be added to with time, and obviously the customer queries will be to, so both need dynamic queries.

I tried this by getting a list of locations by a simple `SELECT name from locations` query, turning it into an array and then looping through that as follows:

```
    For i = UBound(listofLocations) To 0 Step -1
        locations.id = listofLocations(i)
        locations.queryCount= RESULT OF: "SELECT COUNT(id) as recordCount from queries WHERE department=listofLocations(i)"
        objectArray.Add(locations)
    Next
```

This works, but it is inefficient calling the database through the loop, how do I avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The inefficient is because you are using nested query,
you should use LEFT JOIN, and you just need single query

Here is the SQL:-

```
select l.name, count(*) as recordCount
from Locations as l
left join customer as c
on l.name = c.department
group by l.id;
```

And your schema is not very optimized.
Your schema for customer should be

```
id, customer, location_id <-- using name is redundant, 
                          <-- which should represent in ID (location ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I must recommend that your "department" field be changed.  If you change the spelling of a name in the locations table, your relationships break.

Instead, use the id from the location table, and set up a foreign key reference.

But that's an aside.  Using your current structure, this is what I'd do in SQL...

```
SELECT
  location.name,
  COUNT(queries.id)        AS count_of_queries
FROM
  locations
LEFT JOIN
  queries
    ON queries.department = locations.name
GROUP BY
  location.name
```

Using a LEFT JOIN ensures that you get EVERY location, even if there is no query for it.

Using COUNT(queries.id) instead of COUNT(*) gives 0 if there are no associated records in the queries table.

You can then loop through the result-set of one query, rather than looping multiple queries, and build your JSON string.

It *is* possible to build the string in SQL, but that's generally considered bad practice.   Much better to keep you SQL about data, and you php/whatever about processing and presenting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM queries AS T2 WHERE T2.department = T1.name) AS number FROM locations AS T1;
```

I agree that your scheme is not proper, you should reference department by Id, not by name

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for "GROUP BY"

```
SELECT
    department_id as location,
    COUNT(id) as querycount
FROM
    (table of customer queries)
GROUP BY
    department_id
```

As for the database structure... If possible, I would change the tables a bit:

```
Location:
id | name | other parameters

Customer:
id | name | whatever

table_of_customer_queries:
id | customer_id | location_id
 1 |      2      |      2
 2 |      4      |      2
 3 |      2      |      1
 4 |      1      |      2
```

`GROUP BY` will only give you results for those departments that have queries.  If you want all departments, the `LEFT JOIN` option mentioned earlier is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if your `Locations` table really stores `Department` information, rename it as such.  Then, change `Customer.department` to be a fk reference to the `Locations.id` column (and renamed to `department_id`), not the `name` (so much less to get wrong).  This may or may not give you a performance boost; however, keep in mind that the data in the database isn't really meant to be *human* readable - it's meant to be *program* readable.

In either case, the query can be written as so:

```
SELECT a.name, (SELECT COUNT(b.id) 
                FROM Customer as b
                WHERE b.department_id = a.id) as count
FROM Location as a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change your schema, your answer is to do a group by clause that counts the number of queries to each location.

Creating tables like yours:

```
create table #locations (id integer, name varchar(20), other text)
create table #queries (id integer, customer varchar(20), department varchar(20))

insert into #locations (id, name, other) values (1, 'shop1', 'blah')
insert into #locations (id, name, other) values (2, 'shop2', 'blah')

insert into #queries (id, customer, department) values (1, 'john', 'shop2')
insert into #queries (id, customer, department) values (2, 'Joe', 'shop2')
insert into #queries (id, customer, department) values (3, 'James', 'shop1')
insert into #queries (id, customer, department) values (4, 'Sue', 'shop2')
```

Querying your data:

```
select
  l.name as location,
  count(q.id) as queryCount
from #locations as l
left join #queries as q on q.department = l.name
group by l.name
order by l.name
```

Results:

```
location             queryCount
-------------------- -----------
shop1                1
shop2                3
```